# Проблема с ассоциациями переводов от KNP bundle

Tags: php, symfony

В дебаг панеле в закладке `Entities Mapping`
У меня высвечивает 2 ошибки:

> The association
>   Entity\MenuItemTranslation#translatable refers
>   to the inverse side field
>   Entity\MenuItem#translations which does not
>   exist.

И тоже самое для второй сущности

> The association
>   PageTranslation#translatable refers to
>   the inverse side field Page#translations
>   which does not exist.

Использую для переводов вот этот [бандл](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/blob/master/docs/translatable.md).
В сущностях трейты подключены, интерфейсы тоже наследуются. Для других сущностей с такой же конфигурацией всё работает (сравнивал построчно).

Самое странное что при использовании команды `bin/console doctrine:mapping:info` абсолютно для всех сущностей показывает `OK`.

Чистил кеш, обновлял зависимости composer'a, ничего не помогает.

Может что подскажете? Почему через консоль показывает что всё ок, а в панеле ошибки?

Конфигурация сделана через 'xml' и эти файлы находятся в проекте как отдельный бандл

```
src/
    /Main
    /Этот банл
        /Resources
            /config
                /docrine
                    .. и здесь находятся файлы конфигурации в xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы пришлось в конфигурации переводов добавить ассоциации вручную:

```
MenuItem.orm.xml

<one-to-many field="translations" target-entity="MenuItemTranslation" mapped-by="translatable"/>
```

Скорее всего автоматическая конфигурация не работала потому что конфигурация находится в xml файлах, хотя может есть возможность настройки этого, но я такой не нашел. Если у кого нибудь есть мысли по этому поводу, то буду рад прочитать.